# Making Nginx and PHP-FPM code version agnostic

Tags: nginx, web-server, php-fpm, regex, versioning

This is not a question about a current problem but more of a "preventive medicine" question:

I have the following code which is part of a much larger scrip I use to rise up Nginx environments on Debian-oriented systems:

```
sed -i 's/post_max_size \= .M/post_max_size \= 200M/g' /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
sed -i 's/upload_max_filesize \= .M/upload_max_filesize \= 200M/g' /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
sed -i "s/;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi.fix_pathinfo=0/g" /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
/etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm restart && systemctl restart nginx.service
```

This piece of code is the only one from the whole scrip which isn't **version agnostic**. I find this fact a tiny bit "disturbing" because I might run the script a year or 5 years from now with version `7.0` intact and that's likely to cause errors.

Do you think regex is good enough to make the above code version agnostic? Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413933/nginx-version-agnostic-php-fpm-configuration

Comment: It's time for a proper configuration management system.

Comment: @MichaelHampton do you have something to recommend for me?

Comment: Ansible is easy to learn, quick to get started, and can save you a lot of time managing even a small number of servers.

Comment: The idea of using an asterisk (`*`) seems promising: https://askubuntu.com/questions/992464/version-agnostic-php-fpm-restart

Answer (score 3):

Use a symlink.

```
ln -s /etc/php/7.0 /etc/php/current
ln -s /etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm /etc/init.d/phpcurrent-fpm
sed -i 's/post_max_size \= .M/post_max_size \= 200M/g' /etc/php/current/fpm/php.ini
sed -i 's/upload_max_filesize \= .M/upload_max_filesize \= 200M/g' /etc/php/current/fpm/php.ini
sed -i "s/;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi.fix_pathinfo=0/g" /etc/php/current/fpm/php.ini
/etc/init.d/phpcurrent-fpm restart && systemctl restart nginx.service
```